What would be the best option to render typing_extension.Self output type-hint as the class name via mkdocstrings?
I'm looking for advice on how to best render typing_extensions.Self output type-hints, while keeping show_signature_annotations: true option enabled.
mkdocstrings config follows:
plugins:
- mkdocstrings:
    handlers:
       python:
         import:
         - https://installer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/objects.inv
         rendering:
           show_signature_annotations: true
         options:
           members_order: alphabetical

Would it be possible to translate typing_extensions.Self so as that Type is rendered by the class name rather than by the typing_extensions.Self type-hint? IOW,
def func(self, arg: str) -> Self:
    """
    
    Arguments:
        arg: Argument.

    Returns:
        blah blah
    """

would actually output

while I would possibly like Type to output the class name. Alternatively, I would appreciate getting guidance on how to handle such situation; also, does anyone believe - otoh - it is reasonable for it to output Self?
Can anyone advise? Don't know if anyone would consider this a plausible feature request, were this not possible.

Outputting Self means a different thing from outputting a class name, unless the class was decorated with @typing.final. As someone who knows what typing.Self means, I would prefer to see Self. However, you should tailor it to your audience; if they're frequently taking classes from your library and subclassing them, you'd also be better off rendering it as Self; otherwise, rendering it as the class name is acceptable and more legible, if not slightly inaccurate.
